# Как вставить случайную строку из TXT файла в HTML документ?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть HTML страница.
Вот часть кода (iframe сюда не получается вставить):

```
<iframe id="test" src="link" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы значение `link` бралось из файла link.txt, 
в виде случайной строки.
link.txt находится в одной директории с HTML файлом.

В файле link.txt будет 9 строк с URL ссылками и одна строка с переменной, которая берет значение с файла general_links.txt в корневой папке. Тоже 1 случайная строка из файла.

Понимаю что нужно обработать PHP или JS, но не получается.

Comment: у вас в файле будет переменная? это как. В файле или есть запись или ее нет. И зачем Вам переменнаяв контексте этой задачи?

Comment: Из файла загружать ссылки для iframe

Comment: `и одна строка с переменной, которая берет значение с файла general_links.txt`. как у Вас в статическом файле находится переменная? или Вы файл генерируете каждый раз как обращаетесь к нему. и какова роль этой переменной?

Comment: Смотрите, есть ссылка.
При переходе по ней загружается iframe - сейчас это статическая ссылка на iframe, я хочу ее сделать динамичной.
Чтобы при заходе на одну и ту же страницу подгружался рандомный iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?php
    $f = file("link.txt"); 
    $random_line = $f[rand(0, count($f) - 1)];
?>
<iframe id="test" src="<?php echo $random_line; ?>" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Стоит также добавить проверку корректности URL
`filter_var($random_line, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);` (в вышеприведенный код я эту строку не вставил, поскольку не знаю, что вы хотите делать если URL некорректный).

Comment: Не получилось, выдало ошибку что запрашиваемый URL на сервере не обнаружен.
Проверку корректности URL не добавлял. т.к. предполагается что все URL будут рабочими.
Посмотрел код страницы в браузере - url не подгрузился и осталось значение "<?php echo $random_line; ?>"

Comment: @Кирилл Похоже, что у вас php вообще не работает. Может вы пытаетесь вставить это в файл `.html`?

Comment: Да, именно это я и пытаюсь сделать...
Насколько я теперь понимаю - нужно создать файл php и записать в него этот код

Comment: Верно. Вопрос только откуда вы его (этот php  файл) будете запускать. Если вы его попытаетесь запустить с вашего компа, он работать не будет. Но если он у вас на сервере, то скорее всего будет работать.

Comment: на сервере.
Подскажите пожалуйста:
Его как-то особенно нужно называть?
Или путь к нему прописывать нужно?

Comment: Нет. Не надо ничего особенного. Этот ваш .html переименуйте в .php и должно работать.

Comment: Ну, почти...
Видно что скрипт сработал, но не полностью.
Ошибки уже нет, и вместо src="<?php echo $random_line; ?>" значение полностью отсутствует (src="")
файл link.txt заполнен ссылками.
т.е. не взял ссылку